# Numbering combinations of 2 columns' values based on uniqueness in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in which I want to make a new column based on two other columns. this is what my dataframe looks like:

```
    HOUSEID    PERSONID
    20000017      1            
    20000017      1            
    20000017      2            
    20000017      3            
    20000017      3            
    20000231      1            
    20000231      1
    20000231      2
    20000521      1
    20000521      2 
    20000521      2
    20001283      1
    20001283      2
    20001283      3
    20001283      3
```

I need to define a number sequentially in the new column labed 'PERSON_COUNTER' for the unique combination of 'HOUSEID' and 'PERSONID'. everytime there is a new combination it goes up a number and put it in front of combination starting from 1. here is what I mean:

```
HOUSEID    PERSONID   PERSON_COUNTER
    20000017      1            1
    20000017      1            1
    20000017      2            2
    20000017      3            3
    20000017      3            3
    20000231      1            4
    20000231      1            4
    20000231      2            5
    20000521      1            6
    20000521      2            7 
    20000521      2            7
    20001283      1            8
    20001283      2            9
    20001283      3            10
    20001283      3            10
```

I have already tried the code below and it works perfectly, but it takes about 2 hours to execute since I have a relatively large dataframe(about 1 million rows):

```
df.insert(2, 'PERSON_COUNTER', '')

list_person_counter = []
def person_counter(houseid, personid):
  if [houseid, personid] in list_person_counter:
    return len(list_person_counter)
  else:
    list_person_counter.append([houseid, personid])
    return len(list_person_counter)

df['PERSON_COUNTER'] = df.apply(lambda row: person_counter(row['HOUSEID'], row['PERSONID']), axis=1)
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could offer the quickest way.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare selected columns by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) for `!=` with [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)ed values, then test at least one `True` per rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and last add cumulative sum [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
c = ['PERSONID', 'HOUSEID']
df['PERSON_COUNTER'] = df[c].ne(df[c].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()
print (df)
     HOUSEID  PERSONID  PERSON_COUNTER
0   20000017         1               1
1   20000017         1               1
2   20000017         2               2
3   20000017         3               3
4   20000017         3               3
5   20000231         1               4
6   20000231         1               4
7   20000231         2               5
8   20000521         1               6
9   20000521         2               7
10  20000521         2               7
11  20001283         1               8
12  20001283         2               9
13  20001283         3              10
14  20001283         3              10
```

If want working only by one column:

```
df['PERSON_COUNTER'] = df['PERSONID'].ne(df['PERSONID'].shift()).cumsum()
```